# ZPL Center text vertically

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

Is there a way in ZPL to center text vertically?

I know I can use `^FO0,0^ASN,50^FB200,3,0,C,0^FD TEXT ^FS`.  But how can I make that print on the 2nd line if it's short enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a vertical centering feature, but you can fake it, if you know in advance that your string is short enough to fit on the middle line.

Your ^FB defines a field block that is three lines. So your best option is to determine if your string fits on one line... and if it does, insert a "\&" before your string.

```
^FO0,0^ASN,50^FB200,3,0,C,0^FD\&TEXT^FS
```